# MDX Create Member using dimension filters

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, olap-cube

I am trying to create a measure in MDX cube with dimension filters.  The below code works.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SOda] AS
(
    [Measure].[SOda_pre],
    [Case].[Outage Cause].&[CustomerA],
    [Case.[SO Filter].&[1]
)
```

When I add another customer name to the filter it returns #VALUE.  Below is what I tried.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SOda] AS
(
    [Measure].[SOda_pre]
    *{[Case].[Outage Cause].&[CustomerA], [Case].[Outage Cause].&[CustomerB]}
    *{[Case.[SO Filter].&[1]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a member as a tuple, as you did in your first code sample. But you cannot define a member as a set containing more than one tuple as you did in your second code sample. But you can use the `Aggregate` function to calculate a member from a set and an optional numeric expression like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SOda] AS
Aggregate(
    {[Case].[Outage Cause].&[CustomerA], [Case].[Outage Cause].&[CustomerB]}
    *{[Case.[SO Filter].&[1]}
    ,[Measure].[SOda_pre]

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntaxically, the expression cannot be a (measure) member. Wherever you expose the expression to another axis, it will produce 2 results: one against each customer.

can you elaborate on the filter process in regard of customer A and B ?

Philip,